# Arguments to cv2::imshow

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib

**Edit: original title "convert numpy array to cvmat" was a mistake - OpenCV's less than useful error message and my not reading the docs!**

With [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) 2, [IPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) now uses NumPy arrays by default.

```
cvimage = cv2.imread("image.png") #using OpenCV 2
type(cvimage)
Out: numpy.ndarray  #dtype is uint8

pltimage = plt.imread("image.png")  #using Matplotlib
type(pltimage)
Out: numpy.ndarray   #dtype is float

plt.imshow(cvimage)  # works great

cv2.imshow(cvimage)
TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found
```

Since `cv2` uses NumPy arrays by default, there is no longer any cv::Mat constructor and NumPy has no functions to convert to a `cv::Mat` array.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, this has already been answered - you're actually not missing the second argument, but the first. However, I came here with another issue: not every `numpy.ndarray` of type `uint8` can be displayed. I made a slice, to get a single channel of an image, like `red = frame[:,:,0]`, and then got an exception in `imshow`. I suspect it's because of sparsity. `red = frame[:,:,0].copy()` fixed that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function has the following docstring: `imshow(winname, mat) -> None`.
You can see the doc string by typing `cv2.imshow.__doc__` in the interpreter.

Try `cv2.imshow('Image', cvimage)`.

tl;dr : In original question, first argument of "window name" was missing. "imshow" takes two parameters and only one was supplied.

Comment: When I do `cvimage = cv2.imread('image.png')` followed by `cv2.imshow('Image', cvimage)`, no errors are returned and the image is displayed.

Comment: Without importing numpy, they type returned is `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: you're missing a required arg

Comment: As Neon22 said, you are missing the first argument to the imshow function which is the name of the window to display the image in. imshow works fine with images represented as numpy arrays.

Answer (score 15):

The question technically asks how to convert a NumPy Array (analogous to CV2 array) into a Mat object (CV). For anyone who is interested, this can be done by:

```
mat_array = cv.fromarray(numpy_array)
```

where mat_array is a Mat object, and numpy_array is a NumPy array or image.
I would suggest staying away from older CV structures where possible. Numpy arrays offer much better performance than implemenations in native Python

Comment: This is for cv not cv2

Comment: How should we do this in C++ and for cv2?

Answer (score 3):

`Mat` object was needed because C/C++ lacked a standard/native implementation of matrices.

However, `numpy`'s `array` is a perfect replacement for that functionality. Hence, the `cv2` module accepts `numpy.array`s wherever a matrix is indicated in the docs.