# How to convert wx bitmap image object into numpy metrics?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, opencv3.0, numpy-ndarray

I am creating one application, and it is necessary for me to convert wx bitmap image object into numpy metrics. I want to convert **bitmap image object into numpy metrics**.  I want a solution as fast as possible. I have tried many ways, but it can not be done.

This is the main image program:

*please help*

```
bitmap = wx.Bitmap("image/5.jpg")
image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)
image = image.Scale(270, 200, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
control = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, bitmap)
control.SetPosition((0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t google it that much, did you?

- [Converting wx bitmap to numpy using BitmapBufferFormat_RGBA (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995679/converting-wx-bitmap-to-numpy-using-bitmapbufferformat-rgba-python)
- https://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages

Sample from above:

```
import numpy

img = wx.ImageFromBitmap(wxBitmap)
buf = img.GetDataBuffer() # use img.GetAlphaBuffer() for alpha data

arr = numpy.frombuffer(buf, dtype='uint8')
```

Comment: Sir, This will return 1d array that I already tried. I want metrics not a 1d array.

Comment: What are “metrics” exactly?