# Display numpy array cv2 image in wxpython correctly

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, wxpython

I am trying to convert a numpy array (cv2 image) to a wxpython Bitmap and display it properly. I have looked into various solutions on SO and elsewhere, but without success. You can see two of my attempts in the code below.

```py
import wx
import cv2
import numpy as np


def create_wx_bitmap(cv2_image):
    # type: (np.ndarray) -> wx.Bitmap

    # My Attempt based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995679/converting-wx-bitmap-to-numpy-using-bitmapbufferformat-rgba-python/32995940#32995940
    height, width = cv2_image.shape[:2]

    array = cv2_image # the OpenCV image
    image = wx.Image(width, height)
    image.SetData(array.tobytes())
    wxBitmap = image.ConvertToBitmap()   

    return wxBitmap

    # My other attempt:
    # height, width = cv2_image.shape[:2]
    # cv2_image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # return wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(width, height, cv2_image_rgb)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)

        cv2_image = cv2.imread("test1.png", cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  # type: np.ndarray
        print(cv2_image.dtype)

        bitmap = create_wx_bitmap(cv2_image)  # type: wx.Bitmap

        wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bitmap, (0, 0), self.GetClientSize())
        self.SetSize(bitmap.GetSize())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(None, "wxPython with OpenCV")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**The code above seems to work for images under 16-bit (24 bit depth). However, an image that has a bit depth of 64 results in banding like the below screenshot.** (which was a render from Blender 3D exported with 16 bit depth setting):
[image]

I have also tried converting the array datatype, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

**Edit (The Final Solution):**

The solution to my problem was to convert the array to `np.uint8` after *normalizing the data* as mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689428/convert-np-array-of-type-float64-to-type-uint8-scaling-values). Thanks to @PetrBlahos for mentioning that the data needs to be 8bit RGB in his answer.

```py
def create_wx_bitmap(cv2_image):
    # type: (np.ndarray) -> wx.Bitmap

    height, width = cv2_image.shape[:2]

    info = np.iinfo(cv2_image.dtype) # Get the information of the incoming image type
    data = cv2_image.astype(np.float64) / info.max # normalize the data to 0 - 1
    data = 255 * data # Now scale by 255
    cv2_image = data.astype(np.uint8)

    cv2_image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(width, height, cv2_image_rgb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use

```
dc.DrawBitmap(wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(iw, ih, cv_image), 0, 0)
```

but cv_image must be a numpy byte array of rgb values. So, whatever you do, you must convert your data to 8bit RGB (or possibly RGBA, the use FromBufferRGBA).
I do not quite see how your data is structured. 64bits means you have 4 channels (RGBA) each one is 16b integer?

I think you might use cv2.convertScaleAbs, or perhaps convertTo.