# TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

I have the following code to capture data for my beginner face recognition project

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
gray = []

if ret:
    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(frame)

    for face in faces:
        x, y, w, h = face
        cut = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        fix = cv2.resize(cut, (100, 100))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(fix, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = np.array(gray)
    cv2.imshow("My Face", gray)

key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == ord("q"):
    break
if key == ord("c"):
    frames.append(gray.flatten())
    outputs.append([name])
```

It shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/satwi/Desktop/Satwik/MyPython/ML Bootcamp/face_recognition/face_recog_collector.py", line 30, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("My Face", gray)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

Nothing seems to work to fix this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arguments to cv2::imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913392/arguments-to-cv2imshow)

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image

Comment: BTW: cv2 gives you image as numpy array and there is no need to do `gray = np.array(gray)`

Comment: at start you define list `gray = []` and later you assign single image to `gray` but sometimes it may not find faces and then it will not assign single image to `gray` and you will have still `gray = []` - and this can be your problem. maybe you should change indentation and use `cv2.imshow(...)` inside `for`-loop. OR you should use `if gray: cv2.imshow(...)` to check if you no have empty list.

Comment: BTW: if you want to keep all images on list then you should do `img = cv2.cvtColor(...)` and `gray.append(img)` but later you have to display single element from list ie. `imshow(..., gray[0])` or you should use `for`-loop to open images in separated windows, or you should join all images in one image to display all in one window.

Comment: if you get error for `cv2.imshow("My Face", gray)` then first you could use `print(gray)` and `print(type(gray))` before `imshow()` to see what you have in variable.

Comment: When I run the same code without `gray = []`, It returns an error saying gray is not defined

Comment: `print(gray)` is working, it shows gray has some content and isn't empty